# Python. Read specific data from JSON Url?

Tags: python, json, discord

So I'm trying to do a roblox-to-discord bot in python, and i need to fetch specific data. For example:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "user": "blahblahblah"
}
```

Code I've Tried:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('https://verify.eryn.io/api/user/971259772932337675')
print(json.loads(response.json)['status'])
```

Is there any way to only fetch for example the status??

Answer (score 0):

You can load a json object from a string using the json module:

```
import json
response = '{"status": "ok","user": "blahblahblah"}'
print(json.loads(response)['status'])
```

Then you can work with it as it was a dictionary

Comment: I need it on an URL, do i just do a `request.get()`?

Comment: It says the following error: 
`Exception has occurred: TypeError
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response`

Comment: A Response normally has a json method which returns the fully parsed dict.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: do response.json() and the you will get the json Json form of the res. Is it working?

Comment: Did you do ‘response = requests.get()’? If so, call ‘response.json()’

Comment: It still says the same error, don't know why.

Comment: You can remove this part of your code: json.loads(). It's only needed if you're working with a string, but it's already a dict, my bad

Comment: A new error popped up: `'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I noticed that you didn't called the .json method, the correct code is this I think: print(response.json()['status'])